# Regex - Extract TwitterUsername from URL

Tags: regex, twitter

I'm looking for an universal regular expression which extracts the twitter username from an url.

**Sample URLS**

> http://www.twitter.com/#!/donttrythis
>
> http://twitter.com/KimKardashian
>
> http://www.twitter.com/#!/KourtneyKardash/following
>
> http://twitter.com/#!/jasonterry31/lists/memberships

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
^https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?(?<name>[^/]+)(/\w+)*$
```

The sub group "name" will contain the twitter username.
This regex assumes that each URL is on its own line.

---

To use it in JS, use this:

```
^https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?([^/]+)(/\w+)*$
```

The result is in the sub group $3.

Comment: In what language is that? JS doesn't support these named groups?

Comment: For JS with slashes and escaped: `/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?([^\/]+)(\/\w+)*$/`

Comment: PHP is the same as JS (escape the slashes)

Answer (score 22):

There are a couple more test cases to make a universal regexp.

- `https` URLs are also valid
- URLs like `twitter.com/@username` also go to username's profile

This should do the trick in PHP

```
preg_match("|https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?@?([^/]*)|", $twitterUrl, $matches);
```

If `preg_match` returns 1 (a match) then the result is on `$matches[3]`

Comment: Thanks working perfect except there are like 3 empty indexes to clean up to get `$matches[1]` so `$matches = array_values( array_filter( $matches ) );`

Answer (score 7):

this regex works fine in jQuery

```
$('#inputTwitter').blur(function() {
      var twitterUserName = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(twitterUserName.match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?@?([^\/]*)/)[3])

});
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is based on Lombo's answer, works without http(s) too, is less hungry (not keeping spaces after the username) and returns first in the result.

Check it in action: https://regex101.com/r/xI2vF3/3

**For js:**

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?@?([^\/\?\s]*)
```

Comment: best answer i think

Comment: Though this question is really old, this is one of the best answer. But still one thing to figure out, what about `https://twitter.com/home`?

Answer (score 3):

Lombo's answer is my favorite, but it will glom any query string in with the result:

http://www.twitter.com/#!/donttrythis?source=internet

will result in a username of "donttrythis?source=internet"

I'd modify it to be:

```
preg_match("|https?://(www\.)?twitter\.com/(#!/)?@?([^/\?]*)|", $twitterUrl, $matches);
```

Adding `\?` to the excluded character class after the username ensures the query string is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches all four given URLs. The user name is present in $1

```
m[twitter\.com/+(?:#!/+)?(\w+)]
```

Use this to check

```
perl -le '$_="<url>"; m[twitter\.com/+(?:#!/+)?(\w+)]; print $1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me (in PHP): `/twitter\.com(?:\/\#!)?\/(\w+)/i`

Answer (score 0):

I found Lombo's answer to work the best except it would not work if the URL was www.twitter.com/example .   The following works for me on www as well.

```
  $dirty_twitter = array( 'https://twitter.com/', 'http://twitter.com/', 'www.twitter.com/', 'https://www.twitter.com/', 'http://www.twitter.com/', 'twitter.com/' );
  $clean_twitter = str_replace( $dirty_twitter, '', $clean_twitter );
```